# Регулярное выражение для строки из чисел, не начинающейся с нуля

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

**Ожидание:** строка содержит или 1 или 2 числа, строка не может начаться с 0

- *Пробую так:* `"^[1-9]\\d{1,2}&"` - не подходит
- *Пробую так2:* `^[^0]\\d{1,2}&` - не подходит (числа 12, 9, 33 и др не принимаются)

Что я делаю не так? по литературе `[^pattern]` должно исключить вхождение, а где `^-&` должно проверить строгое вхождение чисел

Comment: не вижу комментария Павла с линкой, но нет не дубль. У меня ожидание отличается и в той теме ответа я на свой вопрос не нашёл.

Comment: я сам заметил и удалил

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> строка содержит или 1 или 2 <strike>числа</strike>**цифр**, строка не может начаться с 0

Рекомендую использовать

```
^[1-9]\\d?$
```

Это выражение находит строки из 1-й или 2-х цифр, не начинающиеся с `0`.

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/jU1hY0/2)

- `^` - начало строки
- `[1-9]` - 1 цифра от 1 до 9 (0 исключен)
- `\\d?` - 1 или 0 цифр
- `$` - конец строки

**NB**: При использовании `String.matches` метасимволы `^` и `$` не требуются.

Comment: А что здесь кому-то не нравится? Пожалуйста, объясните.

Comment: Регулярное выражение предложенное вами, за час до вашего ответа было признано автором вопроса как неверным (пропускающим лишние символы), по этой причине я вам поставил минус.

Comment: @Visman: Вы уверены? Я не видел такого выражения среди предложенных.

Comment: Ответ был удален, поэтому вы его не видите.

Comment: Да, на этом SO мне до 10 000 пока далеко...

Comment: @Visman ТС где-то ошибается. Это выражение не может совпадать с 022. Ответ верен, но ТС использует его неверно. Проблема не в ответе, а в ТС.

Comment: @ReinRaus, сейчас как-то это уже без разницы. Тем более у этого ответа минусов нет, я его снял давным-давно.

Comment: @Visman ну да. Просто топнули вопрос... Не обратил внимание на дату. Надо было сразу уточнять у ТС код в котором он получает такие невозможные результаты. Ваш ответ абсолютно верен был же.

Answer (score 1):

`[1-9]?[0-9]`

Первая цифра (`[1-9]`) входит не обязательно (`?`), вторая (`[0-9]`) обязательно. "Строгое совпадение" обозначается как `^...$` (а не `&`),
но в Java принято использовать вместо этого метод `Matcher.matches()`

Answer (score 1):

Для строки из [*чисел*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988)

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Для строки из *цифр*

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы немного перепутали метасимвол конца строки (знак доллара, `$`) с амперсандом (амперсанд, `&`). После небольшого исправления все должно взлететь:

```
"^[1-9]\\d{1,2}$"
```

Comment: знак действительно перепутал - косяк. Но такое выражение, почему-то , принимает число, 022, 333,0000333

Answer (score 0):

на ext js делал так

```
regex: /^[1-9]{1,2}$/,
```

Comment: А как насчет числа `10`?